# Identifying users with a downward trend SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Trying to identify a list of customers who's quantity decreases from their previous purchase.

In this example we see that with each new purchase Mary's quantity decreases over time. However, while Bob shows a decline, he would not yield in the results because on 9/19 he purchased 8 quantities which is greater than his previous purchase of 5.

I'm trying to figure out a query for this for the life of me I can't seem to get it together

```
Customer    PurchaseDate    Quantity
Bob         9/1/2021        10
Bob         9/10/2021       6
Bob         9/18/2021       5
Bob         9/19/2021       8
Mary        9/1/2021        10
Mary        9/10/2021       6
Mary        9/18/2021       5
Mary        9/19/2021       3
Frank       9/1/2021        5
Lucus       9/1/2021        5
Lucus       9/10/2021       6
Lucus       9/18/2021       10
```

End results should be

```
Customer
Mary
```

Comment: What is precise MySQL version?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: @akina 5.6.41-84.1

Comment: Is there a specific period you are wanting the trending to be determined from, monthly, annually, quarterly, etc? Trends are typically determined by comparing the aggregate of two points in order to verify previous point vs current point. Or are you just wanting to know if the most recent quantity is less than the previous quantity?

Comment: @willb it would be what ever time period the user selects. so for example if the user picks to the dates of 2021-09-01 to 2021-10-01, during this period where there any customers who showed a decline in quantity with every new purchase Ex: on the 1st bob buys 10, on the 2nd bob buys 8, on the 20th bob buys 6. bob would appear in the results

Comment: @MikeJone since you're using a date range as opposed to comparing month to month trends, that sounds like determining if the average is less than the most recent quantity. eg: On average Mary has a quantity of 6, but most recent quantity within the date range was less than the average.

Comment: As I mentioned a trend is typically derived from the aggregates of two points, since the initial point is 100% to establish the baseline. eg: for the annual trend `SUM(2018.quantity) / SUM(2017.quantity) * 100` would be the annual trend. If it is less than 100%, it is downward, otherwise it is upward.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT Customer
FROM ( SELECT CASE WHEN Customer = @customer AND Quantity > @quantity
                   THEN 1
                   ELSE 0 
                   END AS increase_detected,
              @customer := Customer Customer,
              PurchaseDate,
              @quantity := Quantity Quantity
       FROM test
       CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @customer := NULL, @quantity := NULL ) init_variables
       ORDER BY Customer, PurchaseDate
     ) subquery
GROUP BY Customer
HAVING NOT SUM(increase_detected);
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=68b75b0df7fe4b383896e78db0caa569

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit tricky, and to find results that are steadily increasing or decreasing you would probably want to use the [`MATCH_RECOGNIZE`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/match_recognize.html) clause, which MySQL doesn't (yet) support. This way you can define a pattern whereby each qty is less than than the previous value. Additionally, you could probably do this with a recursive cte, but that would be outside of my abilities.

Here is what I came up with, with the caveat that it only compares the first and last values:

```
WITH
    tbl (customer, purchasedate, quantity) AS (
SELECT * FROM VALUES 
    ('Bob',         '9/1/2021',        10),
    ('Bob',         '9/10/2021',       6),
    ('Bob',         '9/18/2021',       5),
    ('Bob',         '9/19/2021',       8),
    ('Mary',        '9/1/2021',        10),
    ('Mary',        '9/10/2021',       6),
    ('Mary',        '9/18/2021',       5),
    ('Mary',        '9/19/2021',       3),
    ('Frank',       '9/1/2021',        5),
    ('Lucus',       '9/1/2021',        5),
    ('Lucus',       '9/10/2021',       6),
    ('Lucus',       '9/18/2021',       10)
)

SELECT
    DISTINCT customer
FROM
    tbl
QUALIFY
      FIRST_VALUE(quantity) OVER (partition BY customer ORDER BY purchasedate)
    > LAST_VALUE(quantity)  OVER (PARTITION BY customer ORDER BY purchasedate)
```

Which gives:

```
CUSTOMER
Bob
Mary
```

Or, to get strictly decreasing with a known max, you can chain them all together which gets pretty ugly:

```
WITH
    tbl (customer, purchasedate, quantity) AS (
SELECT * FROM VALUES 
    ('Bob',         '9/1/2021',        10),
    ('Bob',         '9/10/2021',       6),
    ('Bob',         '9/18/2021',       5),
    ('Bob',         '9/19/2021',       8),
    ('Mary',        '9/1/2021',        10),
    ('Mary',        '9/10/2021',       6),
    ('Mary',        '9/18/2021',       5),
    ('Mary',        '9/19/2021',       3),
    ('Frank',       '9/1/2021',        5),
    ('Lucus',       '9/1/2021',        5),
    ('Lucus',       '9/10/2021',       6),
    ('Lucus',       '9/18/2021',       10)
)

SELECT
    DISTINCT customer
FROM
    tbl
    qualify 
        (NTH_VALUE(quantity, 1) OVER (partition BY customer ORDER BY purchasedate) >= NTH_VALUE(quantity, 2) OVER (partition BY customer ORDER BY purchasedate))
        and ((NTH_VALUE(quantity, 2) OVER (partition BY customer ORDER BY purchasedate) >= NTH_VALUE(quantity, 3) OVER (partition BY customer ORDER BY purchasedate)) or (NTH_VALUE(quantity, 3) OVER (partition BY customer ORDER BY purchasedate) is null))
        and ((NTH_VALUE(quantity,3) OVER (partition BY customer ORDER BY purchasedate) >= NTH_VALUE(quantity, 4) OVER (partition BY customer ORDER BY purchasedate)) or (NTH_VALUE(quantity, 4) OVER (partition BY customer ORDER BY purchasedate) is null))
```

Which gives:

```
CUSTOMER
Mary
```

Though for an unknown amount I would think `match_recognize` would be the best solution (or you could add in some recursion or a custom function).

Comment: MySQL does not know about `QUALIFY`. MySQL 5.6.41 does not know about window functions.

Comment: @Akina Oh I see, thanks for pointing that out, I didn't realize he was using an older mysql.