# Find if a number is always increasing/decreasing

Tags: sql

This is related to a question I tried answering here: [Identifying users with a downward trend SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69651248/identifying-users-with-a-downward-trend-sql/69651998#69651998).

Given the following starting place:

```
WITH
    tbl (customer, purchasedate, quantity) AS (
SELECT * FROM VALUES 
    ('Lucus',       '9/1/2021',        5),
    ('Lucus',       '9/10/2021',       6),
    ('Lucus',       '9/18/2021',       10)
)
SELECT
    customer, array_agg(quantity) from tbl group by customer
```

Is there a way to aggregate on a customer and see if a value is always increasing or decreasing? For example, in the above, we'd get an array (if helpful?) that is always increasing:

```
CUSTOMER    ARRAY_AGG(QUANTITY)
Lucus   [   5,   6,   10 ]
```

Is there a function that could do something along the lines of:

```
>>> bool(reduce(lambda x,y: x if x>y else False, [3,2,4]))
False
>>> bool(reduce(lambda x,y: x if x>y else False, [3,2,1]))
True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks at each pair of adjacent numbers in the series and the detects whether any of the differences were negative:

```
with data as (
    select customer,
        quantity
          - lag(quantity)
              over (partition by customer order by purchasedate) as diff
    from tbl
)
select customer,
    case when
      count(case when diff >= 0 then 1 end) = count(diff)
        then 'Y' else 'N' end as Increasing
from data
group by customer
```

If you're interested in detecting monotonically decreasing series as well then you could use similar logic.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=4c7ec7f328091e0799fadb28f1bd4ce3

Comment: cool, what db are you using for this?

Comment: @David542 Anything with CTEs and `lag()` available. Should be most platforms these days.

Comment: got it, it works on Snowflake which I just tried it in: https://gyazo.com/a014a3a29c1ab4bdd314e2209659d6af. By the way do you want to just add that it tests that the number is always-decreasing in the above case?

Comment: the `CASE` statement doesn't work in Snowflake, so do you want to just point out the DB you used to test it out for future readers of the answer?

Comment: @David542 I don't know Snowflake in particular but I find that odd: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/case.html

Comment: yea, it may be a bug. Here's what I get both ways: https://gyazo.com/dfc4125242447dfe8127b65aa8cfebbf

Comment: @David542 It might be the analytic function there. Didn't actually need that anyway.

Comment: awesome -- thanks for the fiddle too!